# Either field is required for validation - MongoEngine

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongoengine

I've created a class for an RSS feed:

```py
from mongoengine import *

class RSS(Document):
    time_added = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

    link = StringField(required=True)
    title = StringField(required=True)
    last_entry_id = StringField(required=True)
    last_etag = StringField()
    last_modified = DateTimeField()

    subscribed = ListField(IntField(), required=True)

    meta = {
        'collection': 'rss',
        'indexes': ['$title']
    }
```

As per my requirements, I want to make it so that **either one** or **both** of `last_etag` and `last_modified` fields are present (i.e. required). Would that be possible within MongoEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-field validation, you can override `Document.clean` method, e.g.

```py
from mongoengine import *
import datetime as dt

class RSS(Document):
    etag = StringField()
    last_modified = DateTimeField()

    def clean(self):
        if not self.etag and not self.last_modified:
            raise ValidationError('etag and or last_modified are required')


RSS().save()    # Fails with ValidationError (etag and/or last_modified are required)
RSS(etag='123456789').save()                                        # passes
RSS(etag='123456789', last_modified=dt.datetime.utcnow()).save()    # passes
```

You can see the [docs](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html#pre-save-data-validation-and-cleaning) for more info.

Comment: the question required the presence of **either** one of the field, or **both** of the fields, but I get the general idea; however, does the overriding of the `clean` method cause any other side-effects?

Comment: No side effect, clean is meant to be overridden (mongoengine maintainer here)

Comment: I've edited the answer so that the requirements matched